# Helping with swift layout (Simple for you not me lol)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, constraints

Hi I am learning how to make newsfeeds and although things are going well I would like some help in terms of the layout of the feed itself. The feed clips to the safe areas of the simulator but I want to move the top section down about half way down the screen. I have made the table view using a XIB and created the table view programatically. How would one be able to shift the top section down? Here is the code:

```
HomeViewScene = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
    HomeViewScene.backgroundColor = Colors.white


    view.addsubview(tableview)



    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PosterCell", bundle: nil)
    HomeViewScene.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")


    var layoutguide:UILayoutGuide
    layoutguide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide




    HomeViewScene.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    HomeViewScene.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    HomeViewScene.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    HomeViewScene.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image: What the simulator shows]

[image: What I want the top constraint to be attached to (that was done on word)]

Comment: Make your information view and add it just above the tableview, and change your tableview's Y position

Comment: Keep in mind that this tableview is within a viewcontroller I just added it programatically. How would I change the Y position?

Comment: Yes, you need to add your view programatically in viewcontroller just above tableview, make sure your tableview's Y position should start after your view's frame

Comment: UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))        UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 50 ))

Comment: Thanks this worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're pretty close. The 2 main things I would suggest are:
1) You need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false if you want your constraints to actually take effect.
2) If you want your table view under your other view, you need to set your table view's top anchor to be equal to your other view's bottom anchor.

Specifically, this is how I would change the code you posted to solve your problem:

```
HomeViewScene = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
    HomeViewScene.backgroundColor = Colors.white


    view.addsubview(tableview)



    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PosterCell", bundle: nil)
    HomeViewScene.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")


    var layoutguide:UILayoutGuide
    layoutguide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    HomeViewScene.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //Add this line


    HomeViewScene.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    HomeViewScene.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.topAnchor).isActive = true //You need to make sure the TOP of the table view is positioned right at the BOTTOM of the other view
    HomeViewScene.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    HomeViewScene.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Remember that if you change constraints on a view programmatically, you must set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false otherwise you will see no change to that view's position.

Comment: Thanks this looks great to use for another time, the more I know the better.